# Get TextBlock inside Button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `Button` with a `TextBlock` embedded inside. When the `Button` is clicked, I want to be able to fetch the `TextBlock` inside it and modify it's members.

Here is how my button is setup:

```
<Button Click="Select_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0,20,20,20">
    <TextBlock Text="My text" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
</Button>
```

In my code behind I want to be able to access the embedded `TextBlock`:

```
public void Select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the `TextBlock` from `sender` here
}
```

I've taken a look at the visual tree of the `Button` but I'm not seeing the `TextBlock`. I called `GetVisualChildren()` on the `Button` but I only see a `Grid` and no way to get to the `Textblock`.

Comment: Your best bet for this would be to use binding. XAML isn't very friendly to this approach, as you've found.

Comment: I agree it's pretty horrible, but I wouldn't say it's egregious.

Comment: This is just about the simplest possible case. It gets much worse. XAML is designed not to be used this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of the `Button` is stored in its `Content` property and in your case, the `TextBlock` is the content of the `Button`.

```
public void Select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)button.Content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do some casting and it's pretty simple

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Establish_handlers();
    }

    void Establish_handlers()
    {
        Mybutton.Click += Mybutton_Click;

    }

    private void Mybutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button clicked_button = (Button)sender;
        TextBlock desired_text = (TextBlock)clicked_button.Content;
        Textbox_Show_Button_Content.Text = desired_text.Text;
    }
}


<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Mybutton">
        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox_Show_Button_Content"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```